# Upgrading ruby gems in openhsift

Tags: rubygems, openshift

Has anyone ever face this issue I mean I have a application which is blowing up since

**openshift** is using rubygem version **1.3.7** I want to upgrade the rubygems version to atleast

**1.5.3** has anyone every face this issue

How can I upgrade it

trying to define the `update_rubygems` command in pre_build hooks  does not work

even `gem update --system` doesnot work

Has anyone ever done this before

Thanks

Comment: What version of ruby are you working with? Any error message when you run `gem update --system`? Try the `Installing with ruby setup.rb` steps described in http://rubygems.org/pages/download if you haven't already done that.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I you follow my question is not about upgrading/downgrading rubygems on my machine but upgrading/downgrading rubygems on `openshift` PAAS just like what `heroku` is

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what `openshift` is :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you describe the issue you're having with 1.3.7 and Ruby 1.8?

If it's a serious bug in the Rubygems library we can look at updating it upstream.  The Ruby cartridges in OpenShift include and run the versions of Rubygems that comes from the upstream repositories (in this case, RHEL 6.x bundles Ruby 1.8 with Rubygems 1.3.7, and we bundle Ruby 1.9 with Rubygems 1.8.24).  However, because we need to work within the RHEL ecosystem it may be a while before any update could be made, and if the 1.3.7 -> 1.5.3 transition is not perfectly backwards compatible it may not be possible for RHEL to update.

There are a few other options available to you, depending on what your needs are:

- Upgrade to Ruby 1.9 - create a new application in OpenShift and upload your git source to it
  https://gist.github.com/2cbccaa65b2a38cd8778
- Implement a DIY cartridge with Ruby 1.8 and Rubygems 1.5.3 
  https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/do-it-yourself

Comment: Sure the app that I have contain which explicitly state that gem version to be greater than version >= 1.4. for example `hoe` which require the rubygems to be greater than `1.4` or equal and there are many

Comment: But I will take a note of upgrading the Ruby cartridges to 1.9